Is there any way to recover previous versions of a file?
Everyone at my job writes code under the same repository, but each on their own individual branches. Specifically, we write to a .ipynb file that I will call "File". There is one master branch called "MAIN" where my boss compiles all of the generalizable portions of our individual work in a single place and includes proper documentation so we can share code with each other. This means that each individual branch and the MAIN branch have a file called File.ipynb. We only push to our own branch (never to MAIN) and pull from MAIN.
Last week, I was attempting to pull code from the MAIN branch into my branch. Something went wrong and it somehow only accepted the changes from MAIN, meaning it got rid of all my changes. This also means the local file was overwritten with only the pulled changes from MAIN, excluding my own work. Since we obviously use git, I did not think it would be a problem that I could go to my last commit and pull those changes back in. However, they somehow disappeared. I am new to VSCode so it may be that I was pushing thing improperly, but it says my last commit was several months ago which cannot be true.
I am wondering if there is any way to restore my code, possibly my accessing the previous version of the local file or manipulating git.
I attempted to pull changes from one branch into another and instead lost everything in my original branch, as well as previous commits and the local file.
This is my git history. Someone attempted to help and I believe also made things worse.
PS C:\Users\USERNAME\source\repos\Repository> git reset --hard HEAD~1
PS C:\Users\USERNAME\source\repos\Repository> git reflog
93d4a14 (HEAD -> Branch) HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to HEAD~1
b7b9970 (origin/Branch) HEAD@{1}: pull --tags origin main: updating HEAD
b7b9970 (origin/Branch) HEAD@{2}: commit (merge): Merge branch 'main' of https://gitlab.com/Lab/Repository into Branch
93d4a14 (HEAD -> Branch) HEAD@{3}: commit: 09192023
0b256c0 HEAD@{4}: pull --tags origin main: updating HEAD
0b256c0 HEAD@{5}: pull --tags origin main: updating HEAD
0b256c0 HEAD@{6}: pull --tags origin main: updating HEAD
0b256c0 HEAD@{7}: pull --tags origin main: updating HEAD
0b256c0 HEAD@{8}: commit: commit4
fbcb7ad HEAD@{9}: commit: commit3
756d688 HEAD@{10}: commit: commit2
be82e8e HEAD@{11}: commit: commit1
33ff098 (origin/Comp, main) HEAD@{12}: checkout: moving from main to Branch
33ff098 (origin/Comp, main) HEAD@{13}: clone: from https://gitlab.com/Lab/Repository


Without seeing the git history of the branch you were using, it will be hard to tell what happened. If I got it, you have a local branch and you merge MAIN to your local branch, which only means a commit. In that case you should be able to revert the commit.

How can I undo a merge? Will this work even if the local file connected to my branch has been overwritten?

You can do revert via git revert (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert). But if you are not confident with git, I would be really cautious because you can easiLy mess up the things. As I mentioned I will not be able to help without seeing the git history.

How can I provide you with that Information?

If you are stand on the branch, you can use git log, but before you would share the logs with us, make sure to blank out all the sensitive information.

Where can I provide it? There are too many characters to paste and I can't add images to comments. Sorry, I have never used StackExchange before.

You can edit your question and include there.

In your logs, you can see the point where you merged the main:
b7b9970 (origin/Branch) HEAD@{2}: commit (merge): Merge branch 'main' of https://gitlab.com/Lab/Repository into Branch

At the start, thats the commit id. To revert to that point, you can use the following code:
git reset --hard b7b9970


I thought this was the ID of my branch. Or at least the detached branch?

This did not return my changes. Only restores the code from the MAIN branch, not including my changes. I still believe the local file was entirely overwritten and with all of my commits gone I'm not sure what to do.

If you can give me Discord or something, I am happy to check it for you. I am pretty sure it can be restored

I left you a message on Discord!
